# Would tags for anime licensors/streamers be a good idea?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have no tags for anime licensors or streamers (examples of which are Crunchyroll, Aniplex of America, Funimation, Madman, etc.). Would we benefit from adding them?<sup>1</sup>

I think that the question [Is the version of Madoka Magica on Crunchyroll the DVD version?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6266/is-madoka-magica-the-dvd-version-on-crunchyroll) provides an example of a question which could potentially benefit from a [crunchyroll](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crunchyroll) tag. Also, it seems like a hypothetical [crunchyroll](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crunchyroll) tag would meet some criteria for a good tag:

- It is possible to be an expert on Crunchyroll (e.g. an avid user or even an employee), and I can imagine some users actively watching the tag (not that it matters right now given our activity level, but, you know, maybe someday)
- It can stand alone in some contexts (e.g. questions about Crunchyroll as a service, rather than specific offerings of theirs - but would these be on topic?)
- [crunchyroll](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crunchyroll) would not be a meta-tag - that is, it *would* describe the content of the question, rather than "something else", whatever that is

However, I could be overlooking some potential downsides to this type of tag. What do you folks think?

**EDIT (25 Dec 2013):** Absent any opposition to this proposal, I have added the [crunchyroll](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crunchyroll) tag to the question mentioned above, and will keep an eye out for other places this type of tag could be relevant.

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course, these tags, if implemented, would only be used on questions that are actually *about* the licensor or streamer, not just those that happen to tangentially involve a licensor/streamer, e.g. a question like "I just watched X on Daisuki and wanted to know why Y did Z in episode Q" should not be tagged with [daisuki](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daisuki).

Comment: Note that we've discussed whether questions about how to use external anime/manga sites [here](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/389/is-it-allowed-to-talk-about-the-use-of-external-sites-such-as-myanimelist/396). Not sure if that should apply to services like crunchyroll which are part of the anime industry though. Anyway IMO it's a pretty good idea.

Comment: I also think this is a good idea, especially if we can find a way to attract experts or official staff from these services to our site.